# Display settings fail to apply on 15.04

Tags: graphics, 15.04, intel-graphics

I installed and worked with the gnome desktop. Got bored of that returned back to Unity. After this I can change my display settings or connect en second monitor to my laptop. It's a dell inspiron with intel graphics card. I tried reinstalling unity control center without result.

When I apply changes I get the following error: `GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files`

I ran a few commands same as another post on here and this is the result:

```
~$ uname -a
Linux neo 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)

~$ lsmod |grep intel
intel_rapl             20480  0 
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
kvm_intel             151552  0 
kvm                   483328  1 kvm_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
aesni_intel           172032  1 
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hda_intel          36864  5 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    90112  23 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
```

Please any help is appreciated... Thanks in advance.

I got these messages while installing.

```
No such key 'external-editor' in schema 'org.gnome.eog.ui' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key.
No such key 'external-editor' in schema 'org.gnome.eog.ui' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_ubuntu-gnome-default-settings.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key. Bezig met afhandelen van triggers voor libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.44.1-1ubuntu1) ... 
No such key 'external-editor' in schema 'org.gnome.eog.ui' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key. 
No such key 'external-editor' in schema 'org.gnome.eog.ui' as specified in override file '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/20_ubuntu-gnome-default-settings.gschema.override'; ignoring override for this key.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the following packages to fix that error:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-settings-daemon gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
```

Please post any errors.

Comment: This does not help.